# Combining two plot in R

Tags: r, plot

I wish to compare the observed values to the fitted ones. To do so, I decided to use a plot in R. What I want to do is to plot X vs Y and X vs Y.fitted on the same plot. I have written some code, but it is incomplete. My plot needs to look like this one below. On the plot, circles and crosses represent the observed and fitted values respectively

[image]

```
set.seed(1)
x <- runif(8,0,1)
y <- runif(8,0,1)
y.fitted <- runif(8,0,1)
plot(x,y,pch=1)
plot(x,y.fitted,pch=5)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code, the second `plot` will not add points to the existing plot but create a new one. You can + use the function `points` to add points to the existing plot.

```
plot(x, y, pch = 1)
points(x, y.fitted, pch = 4)
```

Comment: Thanks Sven. That is exactly what I was after

Answer (score 1):

running plot the second time will create a new one. You could use `points`

```
set.seed(1)
x <- runif(8,0,1)
y <- runif(8,0,1)
y.fitted <- runif(8,0,1)
plot(x,y,pch=1)
points(x,y.fitted,pch=5)
```

Comment: In what this answer is different from the other one?

Comment: It is not, I posted just after the first answer. Must have been quite close as I did a refresh just before answering.

Answer (score 1):

A solution with `ggplot2` giving a better and neat graph outlook:

```
library(ggplot2)

df = data.frame(x=runif(8,0,1),y=runif(8,0,1),y.fitted=runif(8,0,1))
df = melt(df, id=c('x'))

ggplot() + geom_point(aes(x=x,y=value, shape=variable, colour=variable), df)
```

Comment: Unless there is a specific reason to put the data and `aes` in the `geom_points` layer, I think the better habit is to put it in the `ggplot` call, thereby making it accessible to any other layer you might want to add. In this case you get the same result though.

Comment: I guess for `melt` a library is needed, reshape2 ?